# What I have to do in order to use Entity Framework 4 in VS08?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, c#-3.0

I have VS08 SP1 Professional Edition (9.0.30729.1) running with .NET 3.5 SP1 Framework.

I am using [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx) tutorial to build an EF/POCO environment, but I can't find `ObjectSet<T>`, only `ObjectQuery<T>`, so I suppose the EF I am using isn't the fourth version.

What do I need to do to have EF 4 running with my VS08?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot - Entity Framework v4 will be part of .NET 4.0, and only Visual Studio 2010 will support .NET 4.0 as far as I know.

There has not been any mention of a "backward" release of EF v4 for the VS2008 / .NET 3.5 platform, and I highly doubt this will be made available, sorry.

Marc